# Python data frame calculate the ratio of between figure and column summary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume the following data frame is given:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(4,0,0),
                   (2,0,0),
                   (0,1,0),
                   (0,0,2),
                   (1,3,0),
                   (2,0,1),
                   (0,0,1)],
                  index=['mary', 'jane', 'can', 'see', 'will', 'spot', 'pat'],
                  columns=('N','M','V'))
```

One has to calculate the ratio of between each figure and the column summary.

For example the sum of column N above is 9. The value of mary above is 4 and therefore the result should be 4/9.

The expected result is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(4/9,0,0),
                   (2/9,0,0),
                   (0,0.25,0),
                   (0,0,0.5),
                   (1/9,0.75,0),
                   (2/9,0,0.25),
                   (0,0,0.25)],
                  index=['mary', 'jane', 'can', 'see', 'will', 'spot', 'pat'],
                  columns=('N','M','V'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) with sum values per columns:

```
df = df.div(df.sum())
print (df)

             N     M     V
mary  0.444444  0.00  0.00
jane  0.222222  0.00  0.00
can   0.000000  0.25  0.00
see   0.000000  0.00  0.50
will  0.111111  0.75  0.00
spot  0.222222  0.00  0.25
pat   0.000000  0.00  0.25
```